# How to open ConfusionMatrixChart from matlab workspace

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I have run a few models and I do not save any Confusion Matrix info. But, I have save entire matlab workspace. I need help to view Confusion Matrix chart.

I would like to view it like this

[image]

It seems when I double click at the confusion matrix chart it only open Property Inspector

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You *have* the matrix stored, as you mention in the text and show in the image. It's called `cm` in your workspace. What do you mean by "open" it? If you've got a single .mat file with all workspace variables, `my_workspace.cm` will be your matrix (if `my_workspace = load('my_workspace.mat')`).

Comment: @Adriaan I have no problem loading the whole workspace. The issue is when open the `my_workspace.cm` , its only appear the property inspector and not the matrix. I was looking for the matrix value, am I missing something?

Comment: It's a chart, which will open the property inspector. Calling `my_workspace.cm` in the command line will, presumably, result in a list similar to that of a figure handle. I don't know the specifics of this type of chart, but somewhere in that list should be your data.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan, I think I got it , we need to call out _NormalizedValues_ which are stored within the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `NormalizedValues` from `ConfusionMatrixChart` stored in workspace

Example:

```
ConfusionMatrix = cm.NormalizedValues
```

[image]

Comment: As a note especially for future questions where the code is much more relevant: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.